# Exception in Tkinter callback and googletrans api

Tags: python, tkinter, google-translate, google-translation-api, googletrans

I'm trying to write a code for a translation app using python and googletrans API, the code looks fine but there seems to be errors in the tkinter and googletrans libraries. I'll show the code and errors, do help me out if you found the exact reason .

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from googletrans import Translator, LANGUAGES

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1080x400')
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("Exposys Labs--Language Translator")
root.config(bg='#99e5f2')

# heading
Label(root, text="LANGUAGE TRANSLATOR", font="arial 20 bold", bg='#99e5f2').pack()
Label(root, text="EXPOSYS LABS", font='arial 20 bold', bg='#99e5f2', width='20').pack(side='bottom')

# INPUT AND OUTPUT TEXT WIDGET
Label(root, text="Enter Text", font='arial 13 bold', bg='white smoke').place(x=200, y=60)
Input_text = Text(root, font='arial 10', height=11, wrap=WORD, padx=5, pady=5, width=60)
Input_text.place(x=30, y=100)

Label(root, text="Translation", font='arial 13 bold', bg='white smoke').place(x=780, y=60)
Output_text = Text(root, font='arial 10', height=11, wrap=WORD, padx=5, pady=5, width=60)
Output_text.place(x=600, y=100)

##################
language = list(LANGUAGES.values())

src_lang = ttk.Combobox(root, values=language, width=22)
src_lang.place(x=20, y=60)
src_lang.set('-Select input language-')

dest_lang = ttk.Combobox(root, values=language, width=22)
dest_lang.place(x=890, y=60)
dest_lang.set('-Select output language-'
              '')


#  Define function #######

def Translate():
    translator = Translator()
    translated = translator.translate(text=Input_text.get(1.0, END), src=src_lang.get(), dest=dest_lang.get())

    Output_text.delete(1.0, END)
    Output_text.insert(END, translated.text)


#  Translate Button ########
trans_btn = Button(root, text='Translate', font='arial 12 bold', pady=5, command=Translate, bg='royal blue1',
                   activebackground='sky blue')
trans_btn.place(x=490, y=180)

root.mainloop()
```

Errors after running , giving input and clicking on translate:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Safi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\Safi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 41, in Translate
    translated = translator.translate(text=Input_text.get(1.0, END), src=src_lang.get(), dest=dest_lang.get())

  File "C:\Users\Safi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Safi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)

  File "C:\Users\Safi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 195, in do
    self._update()

  File "C:\Users\Safi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 63, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I've tried the latest versions of googletrans and tkinter.

Comment: Move `translator = Translator()` below `root = Tk()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Googletrans API AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095668/googletrans-api-attributeerror)

Comment: That's telling you that `self.RE_TKK.search(r.text)` is returning `None`. You shouldn't assume the match works before calling `.group(1)` on the result.

Comment: What's the fix then?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using a newer Python Api: [google_trans_new](https://pypi.org/project/google-trans-new/) instead of [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/)?

I have run some tests with `googletrans` api and got many errors like

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Some use case examples can be found [here](https://zetcode.com/python/googletrans/).

I didn't encounter any issues when I tried `google_trans_new`. I have tested this on `GCP > AI Platform > Notebooks`:

```
!pip install google_trans_new
Collecting google_trans_new
  Downloading google_trans_new-1.1.9-py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
Installing collected packages: google-trans-new
Successfully installed google-trans-new-1.1.9
```

And try to run

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator  
translator = google_translator()  
translate_text = translator.translate('hello world',lang_src='en',lang_tgt='zh',pronounce=True)  
print(translate_text)
```

Output:

```
['你好，世界 ', None, 'Nǐ hǎo, shìjiè']
```

Please keep in mind if you would decide to use the newer lib, you should remove old one.

Comment: It isn't working, I've already tried it. And the code also requires 'LANGUAGES'.

Comment: This is example of using newer python lib. Above is just example how it would work. If you would like to stay with `googletrans` there is already opened a Github issue [here](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/234) where using `googletrans==4.0.0rc1` worked for many users.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too and it isn't working.